# Reload Unity Launcher to show icon correctly after installation

Tags: ubuntu, package, deb, ubuntu-unity

After installing my own Debian package on Ubuntu using Ubuntu Software Center, instead of my icon it will show a question mark will shown in the Unity-Launcher.

[image]

After the system was rebooted the icon will shown correctly.

But how can i update or reload the icons of the Sidebar, that the user gets the right icon direct after installation?

**Update**: unity --reset does solve the problem with the question mark, but i search for that part of this command, which only updates the icons in the Launcher.

Comment: `unity --reset` has been deprecated in later versions of Ubuntu. I tried `unity --reset-icons` which seems to clear personalized changes to the launcher icons (so that doesn't helper either).